# Can I parse a webpage as a browser would and get back the html DOM element in swiftUI?

Tags: xcode, web-scraping, swiftui, instagram, swiftsoup

I'm trying to scrape an Instagram page using SwiftSoup, but when I run `let html = try String(contentsOf: URL("https://www.instagram.com/sasawpi/")`, I get back a bunch of JS functions and CSS styles [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSTBH.png), probably because Instagram uses React and some package control to send files over from the server. My question is, can I render it as an [HTML DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HDuP.png), like a browser would, and get it as a text inside of SwiftUI using SwiftSoup or some other library. WebView renders web pages so one of my suggestions was to render it with WebView but I don't know how to get this HTML DOM as text from WebView either.

Comment: Did you read the doc of SwiftSoup ? (let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html))

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, I did read the docs. I repeat that my issue is that when I pull data from the instagram website, my HTML doesn't look like regular HTML but like a bunch of JS functions, so all of the doc commands  becomes useless.

Comment: Does it start with <html> ? How is specified the instagram api ?

Comment: The contents of html page header may contains a lot of javascript code, css. If the html structure is there , the conversion doc should work. Look if you have the html <body> in what you get from url.

Comment: @PtitXav, I do have a body but as I said, it's a bunch of js scripts and css styles and no HTML elements. I don't think that SwifSoup can render those actually

Comment: @PtitXav, yes it does start from <html>

Comment: If you look in html returned you should see that JavaScript code is in tags <script > and CSS in <style> . That should not be a problem for SwiftSoup.

Comment: @PtitXav, this might be a lot to ask, but I'm gonna try anyway because I'm desperate lol. Do you have any free time for a zoom or Discord call? This is my final project at uni and I really need help. If I can share my screen, I believe I can explain my issue better.